# How can I create an AWS AMI from a running instance but remove costly data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an EC2 instance that houses an application and a database.  The current instance is running in a production environment with a populated database.  I would like to create an AMI of the instance to use as a template for firing up new production servers but with an empty database.

If I just create an AMI from the instance then I believe it will contain all of the data which will have cost implications due to the size on disk and is also a security risk as the AMI would contain customer data.

I thought that I could create an AMI from the instance, then launch a new instance based on that AMI, delete all of the data, create a new AMI based on the new instance, then delete the original AMI and new instance.

My specific questions are:

1. Will I be able to delete the first AMI if the second AMI was based on an instance created from it?
2. I understand that the charges for AMIs are incremental in nature.  How does it work if a new AMI is created from an instance that is smaller then the AMI that that instance was created from?
3. Is there a better way of achieving my objective?

Thanks

Comment: Ideally, you built this EC2 instance from some automation in which case you would use that to create a new, zero-data instance. If not, maybe create an AMI from this instance, launch a new instance from that AMI, log into that instance, clear out all of its data, capture a new AMI of the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I be able to delete the first AMI if the second AMI was based on an instance created from it?

Yes. You can delete (i.e. de-register) your AMI even if you have an instance running which uses it. But this is something you can easily check on your own. Just create a dummy instance and try creating AMI from it, launch new instance, creating new AMI and so on.

> I understand that the charges for AMIs are incremental in nature. How does it work if a new AMI is created from an instance that is smaller then the AMI that that instance was created from?

It won't be smaller. You can't decrease the volume size when you launch an instance from your AMI. You can only increase it. Deletion of your db from the volume will have no effect on the volume size nor its price.

> Is there a better way of achieving my objective?

Depends how you define "better". What you described I think is the most logical way.

Comment: ok, thanks.  In respect of 1. I have tested it and it worked fine.  With respect to 2., I thought that the size of EBS Snapshot attached to the AMI would be based on the size of the files on disk, not the size of the volume itself.  So if I created an instance and then deleted some of those files and then created a new AMI, wouldn't the new AMI be smaller than the original?

Comment: @altwood Sadly not. EBS volume size can only grow, never go down. You would have to manually copy files to new, smaller EBS volume if you  want to use smaller one.